# Why Owen's selected this function $f(h,x)=\frac{e^{-\frac 12 h^2(1+x²)}}{1+x²}$ for integration?

Tags: reference-request, math-history, gaussian-integral, universal-property

[Owen's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen%27s_T_function) defined as $T$ Owen's function such that :$$T(h,a)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{a}\frac{e^{-\frac 12 h^2(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx$$
,My question here  is not about this integral but why Owen's selected or choosed this function : $\displaystyle f(h,x)=\frac{e^{-\frac 12 h^2(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2}$  for integration ? or just it is of the Gaussian form ? Are there any interesting mathematical properties about it ? Is there any reference discussed the history of this function ?